# Сумма всех элементов в массиве, вложенных в объекты

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий массив объектов:

```
let products = [
  {
    name: 'Серебро',
    weight: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Золото',
    weight: 200
  },
];
```

Мне нужно написать цикл, который возвращает суммарный вес всех объектов. В самом банальном виде это выглядит так:

```
let total = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < products.lenght, i++) 
{
    total += products[i].weight;
}
```

Но как это можно сделать красивее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let products = [
  {
    name: 'Серебро',
    weight: 100
  },
  {
    name: 'Золото',
    weight: 200
  },
];
let total = products.reduce((res, i) => res + i.weight, 0);
console.log(total);
```